# Comparing a Set with a Big Collection of Sets

Tags: mysql, database, indexing, data-structures

### How to match a Set with a Big Collection of Sets stored in database.
[**The collection may have millions of Sets**].
Detailed Statement

[Prerequisite] A cluster has special property which is a set of attribute.

1. I will get an entity having a set of attribute.
2. If i have any existing cluster with exact same set of attribute (neither more nor less) then i will add the entity to that cluster. Else i will create a cluster having property as attribute set of new entity.

Above is the process of the clustering.
The problem is how i should store the data so that the system can run smoothly on very large dataset without performance issue.

> **What kind of database should i use for this? in SQL or NoSQL**

### What Possible Solution i thought of:

1. [MySQL]Store the attributes with cluster in a table so that clusterId to attributeId has `m:n` relation.[table cluster_attribute].
   whenever an entity comes.
   we run.

`select clusterId,count(1) from cluster_attribute where attributeId in("comma separated IDs of attributes");`

But this will not be good since we may find a long list of clusterId's which fullfills the above query.

In the same above table we perform query like.

```
select clusterId,count(1) cnt from cluster_attributes a
inner join cluster_attributes b on a.cluesterId=b.cluesterId
where b.attributeId in("comma separated IDs of attributes")
group by clusterId
having cnt = @sizeOfEntityAttributeSet;
```

This will scan much rows resulting slow query.

2. We store attribute as sorted Concatenation of attribute by any character **|** and make this column indexed.This way we will be able to query faster.But when ever i need to know which clusters have a certain attribute (A1), my query will go slow since i will need to use regexp search in mysql.
3. Items in set is non-duplicate.that is `[a1,b1,c1]` is valid while `[a1,b1,a1,c1]` is not.
4. millions of sets, each will hundreds of items.

Comment: Do you mean "millions of items in a set"?  Or "millions of sets, each will hundreds of items"?  And how many _different_ items can be in a set?  That is, what is the range of `attributeId`?

Comment: And the range of `attributeId`?  (I am thinking about a "bit" approach to the problem.)

Comment: attributeId can be a 64 bit number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have 2 columns in the table for searching.  One is the exact, complete, list of the values, sorted.  It's a long string, probably `TEXT`.  The other is a hash of that string.  I might suggest MD5, then chop to 32 bits and put into `INT UNSIGNED` (or `BINARY(4)`).  `INDEX` this column, but not `UNIQUE`.

Now, to check for existence, do likewise with the incoming 'set' -- build the string, and compute the hash.  Look up the hashed value in the table.  It will give you only a few rows, including some duds.  Double check with the long string.

```
WHERE hash = $hash
  AND str = '$str'
```

The lookup will be quite fast.  The prep work (building the sorted string and computing the hash) will not be too difficult.  It will be quite easy to code in, say, PHP.

Caveats:

- This works only for an exact match of the set.
- It scales quite well.  If you have more than, say, a billion sets, then a 32-bit hash won't be big adequate.  (But `BIGINT` and a longer `BINARY` would work.)

Comment: Hi rick.
I had thought of the solution in addition to my 2nd solution i have mentioned in question.
I am just wondering if there is a solution returning  single record on query.

Comment: The SQL _returns_ a single row.  _Internally_ it might look at more than one, but if filters out the extras before returning.  The string cannot be indexed because it is probably too long -- 3KB limit.  The hash can be indexed (but it is not "unique enough").

Comment: There is a possibility of colliding hash...in that case mysql will return multiple record

Comment: Yes, hash will collide, but the rest of the `WHERE` filters out _without_ indexing the text.

Comment: Thanks,Currently I am implementing the same logic.
But still i am thinking if there is a possibility where it we can have any group-wise indexing.

Comment: If the string is limited to 3KB, toss the hash and simply index the string.  But... you will need version 5.7 to get the 3KB.